# Executing a python script from Visual c# by passing an argument

Tags: python

I am calling a python file from a visual c# form. The python file should accept the argument from c# and process. This is not happening and if i directly execute the python script in IDLE, it works.

```
private void publishAsset()
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Work\Scripts\XML_Parsing.py";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "asset_id.Text";
        try
        {
            process.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

PublishAsset button is calling the python file and giving the value in a text field as the argument. C# doesnt return any error too.

Comment: What does `print sys.argv` in python give?

Comment: @Eric
Here is the code in Python                                                                                    
if __name__ == "__main__":
 Asset_ID = sys.argv[1]
 print Asset_ID
 print sys.argv

Here is the result
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Work/Scripts/XML_Parsing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Work/Scripts/XML_Parsing.py", line 92, in <module>
    Asset_ID = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Your code crashes at `sys.argv[1]`, so never gets as far as `print sys.argv`. Try adding my line before the bit where it crashes

Comment: @ Eric.  Now the code is   #####################################if __name__ == "__main__":
 print sys.argv##########################
but python flashes for a second but i can see the error code as List index out of range

Comment: Yes, but before that error, it prints out the information I want. Can you not read the stdout of python from C#?

Comment: @Eric... I am not able to read that error since python is closing so fast. Anyhow.. i made a small change in my code and i can see XML is generated but the XML contains the Asset_id.txt.